# Function that produces primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, recurrences

For any $n\geq 2$ consider the recursion
\begin{align*}
a(0,n)&=n;\\
a(m,n)&=a(m-1,n)+\operatorname{gcd}(a(m-1,n),n-m),\qquad m\geq 1. 
\end{align*}
I conjecture that $a(n-1,n)$ is always prime.

To verify it one may use this simple PARI prog:

```
a(n)=my(A=n, B); for(i=1, n-1, B=n-i; A+=gcd(A,B)); A;
```

The sequence begins
$$3, 5, 7, 11, 11, 13, 17, 17, 19, 23, 23, 29, 29, 29, 31, 41, 53, 37, 41, 41$$
The sequence is not in the OEIS.

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: It even seems to give all odd primes, with some repetition.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, it suffices to show the following for all positive integers $n,d \ge 1$ (it is vacuously true if no such $r$ exists). If $r$ is the largest thing at most $d+1$ that has non-1 gcd with $n+d$, then either $n+d+r-1$ is prime or there's something at most $r$ with non-1 gcd with $n+d+r-1$.

Comment: @HenriCohen Surely, if $2n-1$ is prime, then $a(n-1,n)=2n-1$.

Comment: I can't understand why there are two close votes (as of this writing).

Comment: @TimothyChow: I hope moderators could intervene in these kinds of matters. Sadly, there are some users who jump to "close votes", prematurely. It appears like a pessimistic impulse.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @TimothyChow If $2n-1$ is prime then $a(m, n) = n + m$ for all $m$.

Comment: @Notamathematician FYI, I wrote & ran (for over $13$ hours!) a relatively optimized C++ program. The main optimization is that, similar to what's explained in Sean's [answer](/a/418302), if $b = a(m-1,n) + n - m$ is prime, then $a(n-1,n) = b$, so can skip the remaining iterations. I have checked some of my results against PARI/GP output using code similar to yours to help verify my program worked properly. Anyway, no counter-examples up to $5 \times 10^8$ were found. Nonetheless, I suspect there'll be a few eventually due to the "erratic" aspect of the increases stated in Sean's answer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't know for sure of course, but I don't think there will be counterexamples, and exactly because of the "erratic" (i.e. "random") behavior. Indeed, for reasonably large n, the termination of the iteration (i.e. first prime hit) comes so incredibly early (like, less then 1% of the total range when $n>10^6$) that a counterexample (i.e. no prime hit all the way through) would have to be more than just a bit weird, see also my comment on Sean's answer.

Comment: The sequence overlaps next_prime(n), for n=1,...,15.

Comment: Observation in Sagemath: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJylj80OwiAQhO9N-g57hJSa2sSLCb6I8UDkJwRYG6zvL2C11VQvzomdBeYbqTQIQQJDuq8rSLIa8MD7aZqcwHm3cLKiGm8RAWdX-atav5QT2m3KaMxZktfEsA10flBXMtF4_w8NO-LpJ5EQzDngJaZAvK9NWj0YP-CynNuIYVAoiaFfejYmfb-stHbSlwgIFiEKNIr0bNc9-w7R4kgSHBY4egcuoVn5&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Answer (score 31):

For the record (not an answer), the function $a(n-1,n)$ for $n$ up to $10^4$ contains 2264 distinct primes, the largest being equal to 20369. I checked that no primes are missing. The growth rate of the primes is close to linear in $n$, see plot.

[image]

I also note the similarity with a known prime generating algorithm described by Rowland in [A natural prime-generating recurrence](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3217):
$$b(n)=b(n-1)+\text{gcd}\,(b(n-1),n),$$
For small starting values $b(1)$ the difference $b(n)-b(n-1)$ is either 1 or prime. Further reading: [Pumping the Primes.](http://bit-player.org/2015/pumping-the-primes)

---

<sub>Mathematica code</sub>

`out=Table[{t=RecurrenceTable[{a[m]==a[m-1]+GCD[a[m-1],n-m],a[0]==n},a,{m, 1,n-1}];{n,t[[n-1]],PrimeQ[t[[n-1]]]}},{n,2,10000}]; And @@ out[[All,1,3]]     ListPlot[out[[All,1,2]]]`

Comment: What is the (approximate) slope of that line?

Comment: the slope is close to 2

Comment: Carlo, are you able to modify your M code above as per the answer below so as to make it "almost instantaneous", as Joachim remarks, to check this up to 10¨6? I am not sure I can. It would be nice to check this beyond that. Many conjectures about primes fail at very large numbers ...

Comment: I will try, later in August, when I’m back from vacation and have access to Mathematica.

Comment: Hi Carlo, did you ever try to do this? I would be interested in looking at it if you did

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not. It's a bit busy...

Answer (score 27):

Extended comment, generalizing @IlyaBogdanov's comment about $2n-1$. Fix $n$ and let $$x_m = a(m, n) + n - m - 1.$$ Then $(x_m)$ obeys the similar recurrence
$$
  x_m = x_{m-1} + \gcd(x_{m-1}, n-m) - 1.
$$
Also $x_0 = 2n-1$ and $x_{n-1} = a(n-1, n)$.
Now from the recurrence it is clear that if $x_m$ is prime for any value of $m < n$ then $x_{n-1} = x_m$. While $x_m$ is not prime it is increasing slowly and erratically, so it has plenty of chances to hit a prime.

Comment: Very useful observation, both for sake of computation (almost instantly verifiable that the conjecture holds beyond $10^6$) and heuristic argument: if $x_m$ above remains composite, a jump should occur at least around $\sqrt{n}$ times (and probably indeed much for frequently), whereas if things behave randomly, a prime would tend to come up after around $\log(n)$ jumps.